Changing a relative coordinate system
I've been working on recreating Boston Dynamics' Spot for the past few months. After addressing the kinematics, I've encountered a significant issue. The way I've set up the leg positions has severely limited their range of motion, particularly around the shoulder joint. I'm wondering if it's possible to shift the coordinate system so that the leg positions are relative rather than fixed to specific values, like [130.43, 58.17, 107.0].
In the attached photo, I tried shifting the system by adding a 45-degree offset to the arm link (the vertical link in the "before" image). However, this adjustment caused the entire calculation to rotate by 45 degrees, so movements like going straight up no longer align correctly.
How can I change the orientation of leg while keeping kinematics relative to its original position.

Programming for Solving Kinematics
def solve_ik_front_right(self,cords):
        # These kinematics calculations will try to be as descripitional as possible but please refer
        # to sheet of calculations by Cameron Bauman. 
        #UNIT: RADIANS & mm
        x_cord = cords[0] #x cord value
        y_cord = cords[2] #y cord value not really relevant rn.
        z_cord = cords[2] #z cord value

        #Find length B using Pythagorean's Theorem
        b_len = math.sqrt( pow(x_cord,2) + pow(z_cord,2) ) 
        
        # Angle of B
        beta_1 = math.atan(z_cord/x_cord)
        
        #Calculations for 'right_arm' and 'right_wrist' applied through cosine law.

        #This is the angle of which right_arm is set. This is necessary for calculating how the long will be SET
        beta_2 = math.acos( ( pow(self.universal_arm_len,2) + pow(b_len,2) - pow(self.universal_wrist_len,2) ) 
                                / (2 * self.universal_arm_len * b_len) )

        #This is the angle of which right_wrist is set.
        beta_3 = math.acos( ( pow(self.universal_arm_len,2) + pow(self.universal_wrist_len,2) - pow(b_len,2) ) 
                                / (2 * self.universal_arm_len * self.universal_wrist_len) )

        #Shouldn't be too relevant to calculations besides for RVIZ, but this is to make the calculations relative to their axes.
        theta_2 = math.pi - (beta_2 + beta_1)
        theta_3 = math.pi - beta_3

        #FINAL VALUE FOR RVIZ
        #theta_3 = (math.pi/2) - theta_3 #Final value of right_wrist
        #theta_3 = (math.pi/2) + beta_3
        arm_offset = 12
        wrist_offset = 3 

        theta_2 = (theta_2 * (180/math.pi)) + arm_offset
        theta_3 = (theta_3 * (180/math.pi)) + wrist_offset

        return [theta_2,theta_3]

References
Kinematics Video

You have two separate problems to deal with: inverse kinematics and mapping angles to servos. Your inverse kinematic (IK) equations seem correct. They generate joint angles relative to your coordinate system origin. No adjustments need to be made to that coordinate system.
Second problem is how to map those joint angles to your servos. If your servos are aligned with your coordinate system, then you can pass the joint angles directly to your servos. However, if your servos are not aligned, you will have to apply offsets to the angles after you calculate the IK and before you pass the angles to the servos.
For instance, if your shoulder servo is physically angled back by 45 degrees, and you apply the IK from your before image, the joint angle would be directly down, but it would result in a leg position like your after image. By applying the 45 degree offset to the joint angle before you set the servo's angle, you would effectively be commanding the servo to move 45 degrees forward which would be directly down.
